# Filter objects inside an ArrayList as a result of multiple conditions in Processing (Java)

Tags: java, class, methods, processing, conditional-statements

I've searched a solution for this and haven't found exactly what I need.

I'm wondering how to create a generic method that accept a **variable** number of conditions, and returns a subset of an ArrayList according to those conditions. Something like:

```
ArrayList<Measure> dataFiltered = allData.filter(
  temperature: 20,
  humidity: <80,
  ...
);
```

I have no idea how to retrieve this conditions in the method declaration, and how to point to those selected variables to compare and create a subset of filtered elements:

```
public ArrayList<Measure> filter( /* ??? */ ) {
  ArrayList<Measures> filteredMeasures = new ArrayList();

  /* Manage conditions in here */

  for(Measure measure : allMeasures) {
    boolean allConditionsOK = true;
    for(condition : conditions) {
      // Point to specific variable set in conditions, and compare with value
      if(measure.[condition(variable)] != condition(value)) {
        allConditionsOK = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(allConditionsOK) filteredMeasures.add(measure);
  }
  return filteredMeasures;
}
```

Comment: Something like `public ArrayList<Measure> filter(Predicate... predicates) { ... } `? (see [Predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Java 8, have a look at how the [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method works.

If you're not on Java 8, look at it anyway, because it's a good example of how to do it, which is to define an interface (Java 8 uses [`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)) that has one method `boolean test(T t)`.

The call then supplies the method by implementing a class, e.g. an anonymous class:

```
ArrayList<Measure> dataFiltered = allData.filter(new Predicate<Measure>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Measure m) {
        return (m.getTemperature() == 20 &&
                m.getHumidity() < 80);
    }
});
```

Or the lambda way in Java 8:

```
ArrayList<Measure> dataFiltered = allData.filter(m ->
    m.getTemperature() == 20 && m.getHumidity() < 80
);
```

The filter method is then quite simple:

```
public ArrayList<Measure> filter(Predicate<Measure> predicate) {
    ArrayList<Measures> filteredMeasures = new ArrayList();
    for (Measure measure : allMeasures)
        if (predicate.test(measure))
            filteredMeasures.add(measure);
    return filteredMeasures;
}
```

Comment: I'll need to have a deeper look to this to fully understand it. However, you've pointed me to the right direction, thanks.

Comment: The method implementing  class works great. However, using lambda expression the compiler returns the error unexpected token:>

Comment: As far as I know Processing 3 is using Java 8, but this function may not be applied.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the lambda had a dangling end-brace.

Comment: I changed this in my tests. I also tried mixing brackets in statements, parenthesis in parameters... I was just wondering if the compiler error is because of unsupported lambda expressions or for some other reason.

Comment: @markusand Post the exact code you're using and the exact Processing version you're using. You might try asking it in a new question, since your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass a list

```
public ArrayList<Measure> filter(List<Conditions> conditions ) {
```

or a [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

```
public ArrayList<Measure> filter(Conditions... conditions ) {
```

but both would be created the same in your loop.